# can we connect multple mongoDB dataSources with spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to connect two databases, two databases are MongoDB data sources, but IPs are different.IP address dynamically we are changing,
please any one help me

I'm working with Spring boot + MongoDB, and I've tried to connect two MongoDB's in a single application, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

i connected an application with 2 data sources... but with relational database, with jpa... maybe the configurations works. I changed all to One DbConfig... if you need, just add more and remove de @Primary annotation

in jpa the namespaces are very important, but maybe you don't need repository, services, and entities, with mongo

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "oneEntityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = {"com.one.repository", "com.one.service"})
public class OneDbConfig {

    public static final String JAVA_COMP_ENV = "java:comp/env/";

    @Value("${one.datasource.jndi-name}")
    private String jndi;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oneDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "one.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup(JAVA_COMP_ENV);
        DataSource bds =  (BasicDataSource) envContext.lookup(jndi);
        String url = ((BasicDataSource) bds).getUrl();
        String username = ((BasicDataSource) bds).getUsername();
        String password = ((BasicDataSource) bds).getPassword();
        String driverClass = ((BasicDataSource) bds).getDriverClassName();
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url).username(username).password(password).driverClassName(driverClass).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oneEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("oneDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        Map<String, String> conf = new HashMap<String, String>();
        conf.put("hibernate.connection.datasource", JAVA_COMP_ENV + jndi);
        conf.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.one.entities").persistenceUnit("one").properties(conf).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oneTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("oneEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

   

}
```

and dont forget set the property...

one.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/oneDS